# Is the derivative of $x^2 + C$?

Tags: derivatives, complex-numbers

What is the derivative of $x^2+C$, except if $C$ was set to the imaginary unit $i$?  It wouldn't be possible to take, or would it simply be $2x$?

Comment: Part of what you find disturbing is that you haven't properly defined the function to be differentiated until you give not only its rule of assignment but also its domain and range. Do you mean $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$? or do you mean $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb C$? Technically, they are different functions. The rule of assignment for the resulting derivative is still $f'(x)=2x$ either way. You aren't dealing just with an *expression*, it is an honest-to-goodness *function*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have, for *any constant* $C$, as $h \to 0$,
$$
\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\frac{(x+h)^2+C-x^2-C}{h}=2x+h \to 2x.
$$

Comment: You mean as ||h|| -> 0 since we are concerned with complex derivatives?

Comment: Even if $z, z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$, we are allowed to write $z \to z_0$. Isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

its simply $2x$. It doesn't matter what particular constant $C$ is.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, if $x \in \mathbb{R}$, then $\frac{d}{dx} (x^2 + C) = 2x$, even if $C \in \mathbb{C}$.

However, this is not generally true if $x$ is *complex-valued*. Differentiability of complex functions is different than for real-valued functions.

As it turns out, if $x = a+bi$, then we have $x^2+C = (a^2-b^2) + 2abi + C$.

Let $u$ denote the real part and $v$ denote the imaginary parts of this function. Then,

$$\frac{du}{da} = 2a = \frac{dv}{db}$$
and
$$\frac{du}{db} = -2b = -\frac{dv}{da}$$

Therefore, by coincidence, the complex-valued version of the function is differentiable, as well. But this is not necessarily the case for an arbitrary polynomial (and in fact is almost never the case).

Comment: Arbitrary polynomials are of course complex-differentiable.  Most functions one would think of writing down are complex-differentiable almost everywhere.

Comment: But one might add that if $x$ is a purely real value, it is not differentiable with respect to the complex variable $z=x+iy$.

Answer (score 0):

The derivative of a sum is the sum of the derivatives, so your first term is immaterial and you are essentially asking about the derivative of $i$, a constant.

As shown by Olivier Oloa, this is null for any constant.

Comment: Haha, an answer that says "yeah, pretty much this, and if you are wondering why, look to one of the other answers on the page".  I wonder if that's frowned upon, given the substance of your answer.

Comment: @SimpleArt: I don't agree.